# Android: how to grant 666 privs to a device via ueventd.rc

Tags: shell

I need to access an USB camera connected to my (rooted) Android. I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2.2. I want to access it with a normal app, so I need the device to be world readable.

I can connect via shell and type

```
root@android:/ # su
root@android:/ # cd /dev
root@android:/dev # chmod 666 video4
```

and it works. But each time I disconnect the camera, and reconnect it, I have to do it again.

Via shell I can remount the root file system r/w

```
mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs /
```

and then  edit the file `/ueventd.rc`  (actually it's  `/ueventd.qcom.rc` )

and add

```
/dev/video*               0666   system     camera
```

But even if I put 666 I only get

```
root@android:/dev # ls -la video4                                              
crw-rw---- system   camera    81,  18 2013-08-08 10:14 video4
```

Is there a way to grant a 666 permission permanently? So that each time I connect the camera it gets the right file permissions?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you look at the standard rights for video4, the group "camera" also has read and write access to it. Is there any reason you couldn't just add every user on the system to the "camera" group?

Comment: Do i need root permission to access /dev/video1? or is there any other possibility without rooting phone? please let me know